Unauthorized to Delete Tweet with OAuth2.0 path on free-tier developer account
Context

I'm using a free-tier Twitter / X developer account.

Admittedly, the OAuth stuff confuses me. I have the following key-values in my .env (values removed), not knowing which are actually necessary and which aren't.
API_KEY=
API_SECRET=
ACCESS_TOKEN=
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=
CLIENT_ID=
CLIENT_SECRET=
BEARER_TOKEN=



The problem
The following is a minimal and (semi-)complete example Twitter / X Flask client. It uses Tweepy and OAuth2.0 to authorize with Twitter / X via an auth url and callback flow, gets the authorized user's info, and gets the auth'd users last 10 tweets. These pieces work as expected.
The issue is when I try to use the delete flow (clicking the "Delete" button on the example), I get a 401 Unauthorized error.
How do I correct this so that I can delete my tweets?
from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, request, session, render_template_string
import tweepy
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.getenv("FLASK_SECRET_KEY", "supersecretkey")

CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
CALLBACK_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback"

oauth2_handler = tweepy.OAuth2UserHandler(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL,
    scope=["tweet.read", "tweet.write", "users.read", "offline.access"],
)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def auth_redirect():
    try:
        auth_url = oauth2_handler.get_authorization_url()
        return redirect(auth_url)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


@app.route("/callback", methods=["GET"])
def callback():
    try:
        code = request.args.get("code")
        if not code:
            return jsonify({"error": "Missing authorization code"}), 400

        access_token = oauth2_handler.fetch_token(request.url)
        session["access_token"] = access_token
        client = tweepy.Client(access_token["access_token"], wait_on_rate_limit=True)
        user = client.get_me(user_auth=False)
        tweets = client.get_users_tweets(id=user.data.id, max_results=10)
        tweet_list = (
            "".join(
                [
                    f"""
                <li>{tweet.text}
                    <form action="/delete_tweet/{tweet.id}" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </li>
                """
                    for tweet in (tweets.data or [])
                ]
            )
            or "<p>No tweets found.</p>"
        )

        return render_template_string(
            f"""
            <h1>Authorization Successful</h1>
            <h2>User Information</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>ID:</strong> {user.data.id}</li>
                <li><strong>Username:</strong> {user.data.username}</li>
                <li><strong>Name:</strong> {user.data.name}</li>
            </ul>
            <h2>Last 10 Tweets</h2>
            <ul>{tweet_list}</ul>
            """
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


@app.route("/delete_tweet/<string:tweet_id>", methods=["POST"])
def delete_tweet(tweet_id):
    try:
        access_token = session.get("access_token")
        if not access_token:
            return jsonify({"error": "Access token not found"}), 400

        client = tweepy.Client(
            consumer_key=CLIENT_ID,
            consumer_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
            access_token=access_token["access_token"],
            wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        )
        response = client.delete_tweet(tweet_id)
        if response.data:
            return jsonify({"message": f"Tweet {tweet_id} deleted successfully"})
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to delete tweet"}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)



This was a simple fix. As I noted in my question, Twitter's OAuth paths confuse me, especially which version (OAuth1.0a and OAuth2.0) is allowed / prohibited to be used with which version of the API (v1.1 vs v2.0).
Given this, I don't actually know why this fix works. If someone could add those details, including when the particulars of which keys / secrets / tokens and user_auth param should be used, that'd be helpful.
The fix was two-fold:

In the tweepy.Client initialization, replace the keys / secrets / tokens with the singular bearer_token and
The call to delete_tweet should include user_auth=False.

This makes the method
@app.route("/delete_tweet/<string:tweet_id>", methods=["POST"])
def delete_tweet(tweet_id):
    try:
        access_token = session.get("access_token")
        if not access_token:
            return jsonify({"error": "Access token not found"}), 400

        client = tweepy.Client(
            bearer_token=access_token["access_token"],
            wait_on_rate_limit=True,
        )
        response = client.delete_tweet(tweet_id, user_auth=False)
        if response.data:
            return jsonify({"message": f"Tweet {tweet_id} deleted successfully"})
        return jsonify({"error": "Failed to delete tweet"}), 500
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500

